# How can I convert a field in list in django template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

please anyone can help me ? How can I convert a field string to list ? I have a field called Size, it means that the field contains somthing as : "XXL, XL, X, SM".

So I want to get something as :

```
<form class="form-control" action="index.html" method="post">

    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="taille">
       <label class="custom-control-label" for="taille">SM</label>
    </div>      

     <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="size">
       <label class="custom-control-label" for="size">XXl</label>
     </div>            

    <div class="customenter code here-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="size">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="size">XL</label>       
    </div>   

</form>
```

What's your recommandations guys ?

Comment: a field to list

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, I already got the answer. I solved it by creating a table with the field article_size in `models.py` file.
Here is the working code:

```html
    <form class="form-control" action="index.html" method="post">

      {% for size in article.size_article.all %}

        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
           <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="taille{{size.article_size}}">
           <label class="custom-control-label">{{size.article_size}}</label>
        </div>  

      {% endfor %}

    </form>
```